# IKImageBrowserView images won't show in OS X 10.5

Tags: cocoa, osx-leopard, ikimagebrowserview

The Apple Demo [`IKImageViewDemo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IKImageViewDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) does not seem to work correctly in 10.5.

The control is there, but there are no visible images. The images are there because when you click and drag where an image is supposed to be, the ghost of the image appears and drags.

Is there an alternative to using the `IKImageBrowserView` for users on Leopard 10.5-10.5.8, or is there an alternative "gallery" style control?

Anything I need to do special in Interface Builder? Any option that needs to be / not be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IKImageBrowserView is available in OSX 10.5 and later:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html

Sample projects that work on OSX 10.5:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/IKImageBrowserViewWithCoreData/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I've gone over several tutorials and looked through a few examples, and my app still won't show images on Leopard 10.5. The images are there because when you click and drag where an image is supposed to be, the ghost of the image appears and drags.